# spark dataframe select one element from array but the value is not the right one

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, dataframe

```
df.select($"onenews".getItem(1), $"onenews").show(5,false)
```

the result shows as follows, the field value getItem(1) isn't right, and the column "onenews" I got is from string's split sections.

[image]

I have known the reason, it's because of spark's lazy computing, the onenews's column is computed from a function which contains shuffle.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: onenews[1]  the value isn't right, see the onenews array

Comment: Arrays indexes started with 0, first element is "getItem(0)"

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question clearly, as per my understanding if you want to fetch 0th element from onenews column, you need to use getItem(0) insted of getItem(1).

**sample code:**

```
df.select(df.col("onenews").getItem(0)).show()
```

Comment: $"onenews".getItem(1)‘value isn't  onenews(1), you can see it clearly in the picture